# glsl - ray marching not working in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am learning `GLSL` and ray-marching now. I tried to convert this [shader-toy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llt3R4) into my `c++ OpenGL` project but failed.

Below are my codes:

```
Main.cpp:

GLuint screenWidth = 1280, screenHeight = 720;

int main ()
{
    GLFWwindow* window = NULL;
    const GLubyte* renderer;
    const GLubyte* version;

    if (!glfwInit ()) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return 1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow (screenWidth, screenHeight, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate ();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit ();
    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth*2, screenHeight*2);

    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);

    Shader ourShader("vertex_shader.glsl", "fragment_shader.glsl");

    GLint positionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(ourShader.Program, "a_position");

     glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "resolution"), (GLfloat)screenWidth, (GLfloat)screenHeight);

    GLint mouseLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "mouse");
    glUniform4f(mouseLocation, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    GLfloat mx = glm::max(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    GLfloat xdivmx = screenWidth/mx; //Coordinates range from [-1,1].
    GLfloat ydivmx = screenHeight/mx;
    GLint screenRatioLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "screenRatio");
    glUniform2f(screenRatioLocation, xdivmx, ydivmx);

    GLfloat timeLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "time");
    glUniform1f(timeLocation, deltaTime);


    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f   // Top Left
    };

    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        ourShader.Use();

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);=
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

vertex code:

```
vertex_shader.glsl:
#version 410 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 a_position;

out vec2 surfacePosition;
uniform vec2 screenRatio;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main() {
    surfacePosition = a_position * screenRatio;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
}
```

fragment code:

```
#version 410 core

in vec2 surfacePosition;

out vec4 color;
vec4 gl_FragCoord;

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec4 mouse;


const int MAX_MARCHING_STEPS = 255;
const float MIN_DIST = 0.0;
const float MAX_DIST = 100.0;
const float EPSILON = 0.0001;

#define PI 3.1415926535898 // That was from memory, so if things start flying off the screen...

float sphereSDF(vec3 samplePoint) {
    return length(samplePoint) - 1.0;
}
float sceneSDF(vec3 samplePoint) {
    return sphereSDF(samplePoint);
}

float shortestDistanceToSurface(vec3 eye, vec3 marchingDirection, float start, float end) {
    float depth = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MARCHING_STEPS; i++) {
        float dist = sceneSDF(eye + depth * marchingDirection);
        if (dist < EPSILON) {
            return depth;
        }
        depth += dist;
        if (depth >= end) {
            return end;
        }
    }
    return end;
}

vec3 rayDirection(float fieldOfView, vec2 size, vec2 fragCoord) {
    vec2 xy = fragCoord - size / 2.0;
    float z = size.y / tan(radians(fieldOfView) / 2.0);
    return normalize(vec3(xy, -z));
}



void main() {

    vec3 dir = rayDirection(45.0, resolution.xy, surfacePosition.xy);
    vec3 eye = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);
    float dist = shortestDistanceToSurface(eye, dir, MIN_DIST, MAX_DIST);

    if (dist > MAX_DIST - EPSILON) {
        // Didn't hit anything
        color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        return;
    }

    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

with this, all I see is black screen. But if i change to `vec3 eye = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);`, I will get the whole screen red. I suspect is something to do with the `surfacePosition.xy` but I am not sure how to resolve this. I did tried `gl_FragCoord.xy` too but still black screen.

**Update 01**

It seems like all of my `uniform` data did not get through the shaders.

I just do a quite test:

```
glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "resolution"), 0.5, (GLfloat)screenHeight);
```

And I still get black screen. While I go to `fragment Shader` and change this line:

```
vec3 dir = rayDirection(45.0, vec2(1280,720), surfacePosition.xy);//<-- explicitly my screen resolution, just to test.
```

Then I got the red circle as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Link Failure: Fragment info
-------------
0(6) : error C5109: variable "gl_FragCoord" domain conflicts with semantics "WPOS"
```

Always remember to check the compile, validation and link status. The problem is that you've defined `gl_FragCoord` and this is conflicting with the built-in `gl_FragCoord`.

Assuming that your `Shader` class doesn't by default call `glUseProgram()`. Then you need to explicitly call it before calling any `glUniform*()`.
Note that any `glGetUniformLocation()`, `glGetAttribLocation()`, `glGetActiveUniform()` and `glGetActiveAttrib()` call does not have that need (for obvious reasons).

You're also enabling depth testing but never clearing the depth buffer. So either disable depth testing or clear the depth buffer.

Lastly ShaderToy's `fragCoord` is the equivalent to `gl_FragCoord`. Your `surfacePosition` however is not. So just use `gl_FragCoord` it's here to stay.

Thus using `gl_FragCoord` instead of `surfacePosition` you should see (like on ShaderToy):

[image]

Additionally `glGenBuffers(1, &EBO)` is redundant and I have no idea why you want to set the viewport to double its size. The call to `glGetAttribLocation()` is also redundant, not just because you aren't using it. But because you're using the layout qualifier anyways.

Note that you also have `time` and `mouse` and equally need to specify those, if you end up using them.

Also like I mentioned before since you instead could use `gl_FragCoord`. This still means that there's no need for `surfacePosition` and `screenRatio`.

Comment: I do have that: `GLint resolutionLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "resolution");
    glUniform2f(resolutionLocation, screenWidth, screenHeight);`, but it still not working.

Comment: By the way, I am using `OS X` and `Xcode`, and did not get the error you have. Not even the compile error from fragment shader.

Comment: It's a link error, not a compile error. Also where are you defining `screenWidth` and `screenHeight`?

Comment: I think you are right that the `resolution` is not going through. I just do a quite test with `glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "resolution"), 1.0f, (GLfloat)screenHeight);`, then change the `fragment_shader` to only `color = vec4(resolution.x,0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`. I am expecting to see red, but I still get black. somewhere between the link have problem.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I have to call all the `glUniform2f(...)` after `glUseProgram(shaderProgram);`, which in my case it is not.

Comment: Yes you do indeed need to call `glUseProgram()` before any `glUniform*()`. Note that `glGetUniformLocation()`, `glGetAttribLocation()`, `glGetActiveUniform()` and `glGetActiveAttrib()` does not have that need (for obvious reasons).

Comment: can you post that as answer so that I can accept it? I do appreciate that you go through the issue with me these whole time.